# Entity Framework 5 performance concerns

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, performance, entity-framework

Right now I'm working on a pretty complex database. Our object model is designed to be mapped to the database. We're using EF 5 with POCO classes, manually generated.

Everything is working, but there's some complaining about the performances. I've never had performance problems with EF so I'm wondering if this time I just did something terribly wrong, or the problem could reside somewhere else.

The main query may be composed of dynamic parameters. I have several if and switch blocks that are conceptually like this:

```
if (parameter != null) { query = query.Where(c => c.Field == parameter); }
```

Also, for some complex And/Or combinations I'm using LinqKit extensions from Albahari.

The query is against a big table of "Orders", containing years and years of data. The average use is a 2 months range filter though.

Now when the main query is composed, it gets paginated with a `Skip/Take` combination, where the Take is set to 10 elements.

After all this, the IQueryable is sent through layers, reaches the MVC layer where Automapper is employed.

Here, when Automapper starts iterating (and thus the query is really executed) it calls a bunch of navigation properties, which have their own navigation properties and so on. Everything is set to Lazy Loading according to EF recommendations to avoid eager loading if you have more than 3 or 4 distinct entities to include. My scenario is something like this:

- Orders (maximum 10)

  - Many navigation properties under Order

    - Some of these have other navigation under them (localization entities)
  - Order details (many order details per order)

    - Many navigation properties under each Order detail

      - Some of these have other navigation under them (localization entities)

This easily leads to a total of 300+ queries for a single rendered "page". Each of those queries is very fast, running in a few milliseconds, but still there are 2 main concerns:

- The lazy loaded properties are called in sequence and not parallelized, thus taking more time
- As a consequence of previous point, there's some dead time between each query, as the database has to receive the sql, run it, return it and so on for each query.

Just to see how it went, I tried to make the same query with eager loading, and as I predicted it was a total disaster, with a translated sql of more than 7K lines (yes, seven thousands) and way more slow overall.

Now I'm reluctant to think that EF and Linq are not the right choice for this scenario. Some are saying that if they were to write a stored procedure which fetches all the needed data, it would run tens of times faster. I don't believe that to be true, and we would lose the automatic materialization of all related entities.

I thought of some things I could do to improve, like:

- Table splitting to reduce the selected columns
- Turn off object tracking, as this scenario is read only (have untracked entities)

With all of this said, the main complaint is that the result page (done in MVC 4) renders too slowly, and after a bit of diagnostics it seems all "Server Time" and not "Network Time", taking about from 8 to 12 seconds of server time.

From my experience, this should not be happening. I'm wondering if I'm approaching this query need in a wrong way, or if I have to turn my attention to something else (maybe a bad configured IIS server, or anything else I'm really clueless). Needles to say, the database has its indexes ok, checked very carefully by our dba.

So if anyone has any tip, advice, best practice I'm missing about this, or just can tell me that I'm dead wrong in using EF with Lazy Loading for this scenario... you're all welcome.

Comment: FWIW, I've been maintaining (quite happily) my own ORM for years (before EF existed). I've found that automation starts to break down when complex loads are involved. I usually write a stored procedure to get the data I need for a complex object tree, and then pass it off to helpers which automate the instantiation/mapping. It doesn't have to involve a great deal of code and--done properly--it will be very, very fast. Even if your 300 calls execute quickly, do you really want 300 calls when 1 will do? I have no problem with a chatty relationship on a fast network, but that's excessive.

Comment: So I would have to manually mantain the code to materialize every entity from the returned sql. The entities/tables of this database are around the 100ish. Are you sure this would be a mantainable solution? Because it does seem not to me.

Comment: I'd suggest profiling the code and identifying the exact hotspots. You say that it's "server time"; attach a profiler (e.g. the one in VS) and find out where it's spending the time. And yes, maintaining a stored procedure that returns dozens of tables can be challenging (although not that bad if the schema doesn't change). I would hope that materialization can still be somewhat automated (not sure what capabilities EF has for mixing manual calls with automated loads).

Answer (score 4):

For a very complex query that brings up tons of hierarchical data, stored procs won't generally help you performance-wise over LINQ/EF if you take the right approach. As you've noted, the two "out of the box" options with EF (lazy and eager loading) don't work well in this scenario. However, there are still several good ways to optimize this:

(1) Rather than reading a bunch of entities into memory and then mapping via automapper, do the "automapping" directly in the query where possible. For example:

```
var mapped = myOrdersQuery.Select(o => new OrderInfo { Order = o, DetailCount = o.Details.Count, ... })
    // by deferring the load until here, we can bring only the information we actually need 
    // into memory with a single query
    .ToList();
```

This approach works really well if you only need a subset of the fields in your complex hierarchy. Also, EF's ability to select hierarchical data makes this much easier than using stored procs if you need to return something more complex than flat tabular data.

(2) Run multiple LINQ queries by hand and assemble the results in memory. For example:

```
// read with AsNoTracking() since we'll be manually setting associations
var myOrders = myOrdersQuery.AsNoTracking().ToList();
var orderIds = myOrders.Select(o => o.Id);
var myDetails = context.Details.Where(d => orderIds.Contains(d.OrderId)).ToLookup(d => d.OrderId);
// reassemble in memory
myOrders.ForEach(o => o.Details = myDetails[o.Id].ToList());
```

This works really well when you need all the data and still want to take advantage of as much EF materialization as possible. Note that, in most cases a stored proc approach can do no better than this (it's working with raw SQL, so it has to run multiple tabular queries) but can't reuse logic you've already written in LINQ.

(3) Use Include() to manually control which associations are eager-loaded. This can be combined with #2 to take advantage of EF loading for some associations while giving you the flexibility to manually load others.

Answer (score 2):

Try to think of an efficient yet simple sql query to get the data for your views.

Is it even possible?

If not, try to **decompose** (denormalize) your tables so that less joins is required to get data. Also, are there efficient indexes on table colums to speed up data retrieval?

If yes, forget EF, write a stored procedure and use it to get the data.

Turning tracking off for selected queries is a-must for a read-only scenario. Take a look at my numbers:

http://netpl.blogspot.com/2013/05/yet-another-orm-micro-benchmark-part-23_15.html

As you can see, the difference between tracking and notracking scenario is significant.

I would experiment with eager loading but not everywhere (so you don't end up with 7k lines long query) but in selected subqueries.

Comment: That's interesting to say the least. I still wonder why Model First is faster than Code First. Anyway changing the database is not an option, as I'm not in the position to make that call, also that database is a readonly database, mirrored from another sql, which is populated by jobs that fetch data from a 20 year old AS400.. you get the picture :)

Comment: Code first uses model first internally so it pays the price of wrapping things as far as I understand.

Comment: Tried to turn tracking off, but almost nothing changed. We're using Skip/Take to get only 10 results at a time from the main entity. I also tried to parallelize the transformation of automapper, gained 1.5 seconds, but still not near. Denormalizing, even with a view or a sproc, seems wrong. We did a lot of work to normalize our data structure from an old version, so now I would have to query it to get it denormalized, then write a bunch of manual mapping code to convert it in normalized objects? Aw :(

Comment: With 10 entites per query, ef will be much slower than a raw sqlcommand. The number of queries is also a problem. If you can't render your views with only few queries, you probably have to rethink the approach.

Answer (score 0):

One point to consider, EF definitely helps make development time much quicker. However, you must remember that when you're returning lots of data from the DB, that EF is using **dynamic SQL**. This means that EF must 1. Create the SQL, 2.SQL Server then needs to create an execution plan. this happens before the query is run.

When using stored procedures, SQL Server can cache the execution plan (which can be edited for performance), which does make it faster than using EF. BUT... you can always create your stored proc and then execute it from EF. Any complex procedures or queries I would convert to stored procs and then call from EF. Then you can see your performance gain(s) and reevaluate from there.

Comment: As a note, I believe EF tries to cache the queries it creates to avoid having to visit the complete expression tree with every request. SQL Server will definitely try to cache the execution plan, even if the query doesn't reside in a stored procedure. However, for the OP's purposes, a stored proc very well may be the correct solution.

Comment: While EF does caching, but that is much different than SQL Server caching. EF can not cache a SQL Server execution plan for example. And for queries returning lots of data you will be surprised of how much a difference this can make. When I write large scale applications I most of the time EF, but when speed is critical (I work in finance), stored procs are a must.

Comment: I'm aware of the differences...I'm talking about 2 different things. What I said was that 1) I think EF caches the (very expensive) traversal of the expression tree used to create the SQL query and 2) SQL Server will try to optimize the query itself, even if it isn't in a stored proc. Still, I think we agree on the fundamental approach (see my comments on the question). Complex tree population is often a very good reason to create a custom stored procedure. It's very hard for an automated system to infer the most optimum way to load data like this.

Answer (score 0):

In some cases, you can use Compiled Queries [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb896297.aspx) to improve query performance drastically.  The idea is that if you have a common query that is run many times that might generate the same SQL call with different parameters, you compile the query tie first time it's run then pass it as a delegate, eliminating the overhead of Entity Framework re-generating the SQL for each subsequent call.